# Is Leaky Relu with alpha = 1 a linear activation function?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, activation-function

if I set alpha = 1, then I simply extend the normal Relu function down. Should this function then be viewed as a linear activation function?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Leaky ReLU with alpha equals to 1 is in fact the linear activation function.

Comment: You are welcome! If the post answered your question. Please mark it as answered.